# Return T/F with dcast instead of the count

Tags: r, reshape2

I've got a table, df:

```
Type  Color
 aaa    Red
 aaa   Blue
 bbb    Red
 bbb    Red
```

Which for the code `dcast(df, Type ~ Color, length)` returns:

```
Type  Red   Blue
 aaa    1      1
 bbb    2      0
```

What I'd like to do is return the true false or 1/0 version of that. So the output would represent 1 where the variable exists in the input and zero when it doesn't, with output like:

```
Type  Red   Blue
 aaa    1      1
 bbb    1      0
```

I can hack this a bit by extracting the matrix and dividing it by itself, but was hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Like `dcast(df, Type ~ Color, function(x) length(x)>1)`?

Comment: Do you need to use `dcast` to do this? Why not just `table`, as in `(table(mydf) > 0) * 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy with the logical answer

then

```
dcast(adf, Type ~ Color, function(x) any(length(x)))
```

Comment: Worked great thanks. I was also able to adjust it to binary output by multiplying the function by 1.
>dcast(adf, Type ~ Color, function(x) any(length(x))*1)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own function, and return the desired quantity

```
dcast(adf, Type ~ Color, function(x) as.numeric(length(x) > 0))
```